# Read more text at the end of multi line truncated-ellipsis text

Tags: html, css

**I don't need to expand/collapse the text, read more will be a hyperlink. I only need static visual properties.**

In code snippet below (optimally, look at it in full page), in the first paragraph, it is how it looks like when there is overflow.

On second paragraph, there is no overflow and it looks fine.

On third paragraph, it is how I want it to look like when there is overflow. I want only the card_def to truncate, and read more text to be at the end of third line.

```css
.card_short {
    max-height: 65px;
    max-width: 603px;
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-line-clamp: 3;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.card_def {
    font-size: 16px;
    display: inline;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.card_readmore {
    font-size: 16px;
    display: inline;
    color: #0057b3;
}
```

```html
<div>This is how it looks when there is an overflow, I don't want this:</div>
<div class="card_short">
  <h3 class="card_def">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</h3>
  <h3 class="card_readmore">Read more</h3>
</div>
<br><br>

<div>When there isn't overflow, this paragraph is fine:</div>
<div class="card_short">
  <h3 class="card_def">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum... There is no overflow here.</h3>
  <h3 class="card_readmore">Read more</h3>
</div>
<br><br>

<div>I want the first paragraph to look like this:</div>
<div class="card_short">
  <h3 class="card_def">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type s...</h3>
  <h3 class="card_readmore">Read more</h3>
</div>
```

Comment: One minor point, don't use `display: -webkit-box;`. This is an old non-standard implementation of flexbox

Comment: Thank you for the point. How to make text  truncate-elipsis on overflow after a determined number of lines, without making use of `-webkit-line-clamp`

Comment: Consider setting the height of the contain to be that of 3 lines' height?

Comment: I tried but text went beyond div and `word-wrap:break-word;` didn't work.

Comment: I don't see any major stylistic changes between the desired result (1) vs undesired (3). They both look the same, just one has more text.

Comment: @Kameron Read more text is supposed to be a hyperlink so you can't click on it and go to another page to read more if it is not visible.

Comment: I guess the main issue is to get the read more to be at the end of the dots instead of on another line

Comment: While old, without `display: -webkit-box` the *line-clamp*  mechanism will not function. Where `overflow: hidden; max-width: ...; text-overflow: ellipsis; white-space: nowrap` crops an element horizontally, `display: -webkit-box; -webkit-box-orient: vertical; -webkit-line-clamp: ...` crops an element vertically. Let me know if this [Demo on Codepen](https://codepen.io/renevanderlende/pen/JjpeaZX?editors=1100) I created last month does what you need then I will post a simplified version as my answer. Just added **[Toggle 'read more']** for you to check. Works in conjuction with 'max lines'...

Comment: I am not sure if it is possible to have the read more follow the dots unless the text have the dots in it already. You may have to settle for read more on the next line which is quite easy to achieve.

Comment: Yeah, it looks like there's no possible solution for such requirement only using HTML and CSS. I decided to make it manually, using Javascript, cutting the `card_def` text short if it exceeds some string length. It isn't the most optimal solution but works pretty okay for now. Thanks for all the answers.

Answer (score 1):

Target the first `.card_short` and give this element a `max-height: 100%;`.

```css
.card {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 603px;
}

.card_short {
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 3;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.card_def {
  font-size: 16px;
  display: inline;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.card_readmore {
  font-size: 16px;
  display: inline;
  color: #0057b3;
  position: absolute;
  right: 12px;
  bottom: -16px;
  background-color: white;
}

.d-none {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <div>This is how it looks when there is an overflow, I don't want this:</div>
  <div class="card_short">
    <h3 class="card_def">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It
      has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
      publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</h3>
    <h3 class="card_readmore" style="bottom: 32px;">...Read more</h3>
  </div>
  <br><br>
</div>


<div class="card">
  <div>When there isn't overflow, this paragraph is fine:</div>
  <div class="card_short">
    <h3 class="card_def">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum... There is no overflow here.</h3>
    <h3 class="card_readmore d-none">...Read more</h3>
    <!-- no overflow content, no read more -->
  </div>
  <br><br>
</div>

<div class="card">

  <div>I want the first paragraph to look like this:</div>
  <div class="card_short">
    <h3 class="card_def">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type s</h3>
    <h3 class="card_readmore">...Read more</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't think this is what the OP want

Comment: Thank you for your answer but doesn't solve the problem, sorry. I cannot add seperate classes for each paragraph. There is supposed to be tens of paragraphs with variable lengths and they are nested inside equal size cards.

I added 3 different scenarios of text length in the code snippet just to give a visual example. For a correct solution, first and third paragraph should look identical, or at least similar, without changing class names.

Comment: @zibidigonzales voted to close. To avoid getting the question closed I'd suggest adding some sort of markup image or a more detailed explanation. In its current state, the question is unclear.

Comment: @Kameron " I want only the card_def to truncate, and read more text to be at the end of **third** line."
I don't know how more I can be clear. I explained it with HTML code instead of markup image.

Comment: it is clear to me what the OP want, but there is a much simpler way to ask this question which is too much to explain here

Comment: @zibidigonzales See edits. If you're going to use a `-webkit-line-clamp: 3;` for all paragraphs this will work nicely.  Hope that helps.

Comment: @Huangism I don't know much about front-end terminology, maybe I couldn't explain simpler because of it. Sorry for that.

Comment: I think your third paragraph explains everything, the 2 above might have confused people but as I mentioned before I am not sure if this is possible and even having the dots for 3 lines is not solid css. The only way I see this working is if the text is already truncated with the dots, and you can add read more at the end but using css to dot the text, I don't think this will work

Comment: Thank you @Kameron, but unfortunately, it doesn't satisfy my needs as well. It is probably not possible to achieve such thing using CSS and HTML. Thank you for your time.